# Why `overscroll-behavior: contain` is not working in this case?

Tags: html, css

I am using `overscroll-behavior: contain` here in the list, but when I hover over the list and want only the list to scroll, the whole body content is moving.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Upload Details</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="UploadDetails.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="form">
            <h1>Heading</h1>
            <h1>Heading</h1>
            <h1>Heading</h1>
            <h1>Heading</h1>
            <h1>Heading</h1>
            <h1>Heading</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="list">
            <ul>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
                <li>List Item</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
}
#container{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
.form{
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
h1{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.list{
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    border-left: 2px solid black;
}
ul{
    overflow: auto;
    overscroll-behavior: contain;
    list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because you have not defined `height` to `ul`

I have added `height` to `ul` and its working please see below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.form {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.list {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
}

ul {
  overflow: auto;
  overscroll-behavior: contain;
  list-style: none;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Upload Details</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="UploadDetails.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="form">
      <h1>Heading</h1>
      <h1>Heading</h1>
      <h1>Heading</h1>
      <h1>Heading</h1>
      <h1>Heading</h1>
      <h1>Heading</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="list">
      <ul>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```